# How to share video by slack?

Tags: android, sharing, file-sharing, android-sharing, data-sharing

I made an implementation of share video and all works when I share video by WhatsUp. But I noticed that if I share video by Slack it doesn't play in Slack. It means I got the video file in my Slack account, click on it and it doesn't play... I can download this video and it will play, but in Slack it doesn't.

If I share a video from standard Gallery app to Slack it works...

So, what is the difference?

Here my sharing code

```
private fun openShareDialog(iC: Context, //
                            iPath: String) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(//
            iC.applicationContext, //
            arrayOf(iPath), null //
    ) { _, iUri ->
        var shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        shareIntent.type = "video/*"
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "title")
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "title")
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, iUri)
        shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, iC.getString(R.string.tetavi_send_to))
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        iC.startActivity(shareIntent)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("*/*");
            sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "title");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath()));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share file with"));
```

Comment: posting some code without any explanation can not accept as a correct answer, please describe how your answer can solve the problem.